# Integrate $ \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)e^{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}$ around a sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'd like some advice with the following exercise,

Solve $$\iiint\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)e^{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}dxdydz$$ for the domain $$D=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\le r^2, x\ge 0, y\ge 0, z\ge 0\}$$

My first attempt was to use spherical coordinates and change the domain to be $$D=\{0\le \rho \le r,0\le \varphi \le \frac{\pi}{2}, 0\le \phi\le \frac{\pi}{2}\}$$

And the function being $f(\rho,\varphi,\phi)=\rho e^{\rho^4}$
Then the integral being redefined as $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{r}\rho^2e^{\rho^4}\ d\rho\ d\varphi\ d\phi$$

And here's where the problem shows up, which obviously is $\int \rho^2e^{\rho4}d\rho$ function who's primitive is not pretty at all so this is definitely not the path I should be taking. At this point I though both of using Cartesian coordinates and cylindrical coordinates both neither helped, so any help would be really appreciated!

Sorry for the not so pretty equations, I'm still learning to use MathJax

Comment: Double check your work transforming your integral into spherical. The volume element doesn't look right.

Comment: @zahbaz I'm sorry but what exactly are you referring to by volume element?

Comment: It's cool. Volume element refers to the differential volume that you are integrating over. $dV = dx\ dy\ dz$ in cartesian. In spherical it's $dV = r^2 \sin\phi\ dr\ d\phi\ d\theta$ where I'm defining $\phi$ as my polar angle. If you studied the Jacobian, that's the result you get when you transform from cartesian to polar.

Comment: Ah yes now I know what you mean, I only added a single $\rho$ as in polar coordinates, my bad right there. Now I see that obvious substitution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the change of variables theorem, the volume element should not be $d\rho\,d\theta\,d\phi$, but rather ($\varphi$ is the diffeomorphism from spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates, and $\theta$ is the inclination)
$$|\operatorname{det} D\boldsymbol{\varphi}|
= \operatorname{abs}\begin{vmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\phi&& \rho\cos\theta\cos\phi&& -\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
\sin\theta\sin\phi&& \rho\cos\theta\sin\phi&& \rho\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
\cos\theta&& -\rho\sin\theta&& 0
\end{vmatrix} = |\rho^2 \sin\theta| = \rho^2 \sin\theta
$$
so $dx\,dy\,dz = \rho^2 \sin\theta\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta$, and your integral becomes
$$ \int_D \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \exp((x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2)dx\,dy\,dz
= \int_D \rho^3 \exp \rho^4 \sin\theta\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta
$$